# Tensorflow w/ XLA causing a memory leak

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla, xla

I'm training the [EfficientDet](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet/tf2) neural network with Tensorflow 2.9 in a Docker container.

Without XLA compilation, everything runs fine. With XLA, I'm getting a 4x performance boost! However, there is a memory leak that increases RAM usage until things crash.

I enabled XLA by adding an environment variable to my Dockerfile like so:

```
ENV TF_XLA_FLAGS="--tf_xla_auto_jit=2 --tf_xla_cpu_global_jit"
```

This is happening on [EfficientDet](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet/tf2) but not [EfficientNetV2](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientnetv2). The leak does not affect GPU memory, only RAM.

Any ideas?